# QGIS, displaying attribute values over geographies

Tags: qgis, symbology, fields-attributes

Is there a way to use graduated symbols that display a value off the attribute table? For example, I have a map of Vermont towns, and I would like to have an industry code floating above each town (I am using a color gradient to show unemployment rate, so I need another method to compare industry). I'm guessing I cannot, because I cannot reference to this anywhere or previous questions on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:
 1. Create a copy of the layer by right clicking and hitting 'Duplicate'
 2. Place this layer over the top of your first layer.
 3. Change the style of this layer by doing a transparent fill and keep the border color the same as your original layer.
 4. Under 'Labels' tab, turn on your labels for the industry code (assuming that the industry code is a column within your data) and format it however you like.